# Convert std::ostringstream into std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream, ostringstream

The next code returns an empty string in ss:

```
#include <string>       
#include <iostream>     
#include <sstream>      

int main () {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "Text";

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
  std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

How can I return from *ss* the text introduced in oss? I'm mainly interested in converting std::ostringstream into std::stringstream.

Comment: Why can't you use `oss.str()` instead? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The real problem is too long, but it will be solved if I find the solution to this one.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist read again what is the nature of `XY problem` (length has nothing to that), you are asking how to fix your invalid solution not how to properly resolve actual problem.

Comment: If you have stuff in ss, and you are trying to concat ss with oss you can just use `std::cout << ss.str() << oss.str() << "\n";` This is more efficient then trying to combine them into a single object just to print.  If you need a single string then just return `ss.str() + oss.str()`

Comment: Lets take a step back and look at what you are asking to see why you can't do this.  `oss` is an **output** stream.  When you do `ss.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());` (or the shorthand of `ss << oss.rdbuf()`) you are asking to **read** from `oss`.  That's not going to work as `oss` is for **writing** to, not reading from.

Comment: Thanks, @NathanOliver. Is there any way to convert std::ostringstream into std::stringstream without using .str()?

Comment: AFAIK, No.  `oss` is for writing to, not reading from.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist Didn't my answer do what you wanted?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your answer, it was very useful. But the most helpful solution was the comment of NathanOliver.

Comment: @Medicalphysicist You are welcome. How did you manage to use Nathans comment to "_return from ss the text introduced in oss_"? You should write an answer to your question yourself and describe how so that others may make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following comments from *@NathanOliver*, I decided to convert *std::ostringstream* into *std::stringstream* by using *str()*:

```
#include <string>       
#include <iostream>     
#include <sstream>      

int main () {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "Text";

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << oss.str();
  std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, though this isn't an answer to the question, while my answer does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the protected [`std::streambuf::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/swap) member function that exchanges the contents of the stream buffer with those of another

To get access to it, you'll need a derived class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct swapper : std::streambuf {
    using std::streambuf::streambuf;
    void swap(std::streambuf& rhs) {         // public proxy for protected swap
        std::streambuf::swap(rhs);
    }
};

// casting
void swapbuf(std::ostream& a, std::ostream& b) {
    static_cast<swapper*>(a.rdbuf())->swap(*b.rdbuf());
}

int main () {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Text";
    std::stringstream ss;
    swapbuf(oss, ss);

    std::cout << "ss:  " << ss.str() << "\n";   // prints Text
}
```

Comment: That's exactly why "protected" is a bad idea. Abuse like this.

Comment: @MartinYork I guess one could replace the `streambuf`s in the stringstreams with instances of the customized `streambuf` to make it non-abusive.